# How can I add class name dynamically in xpath?

Tags: python-3.x

I want to add class name dynamically.

I am using Python 3 with Selenium to scrape...

```py
new = "dt du dv bs dw dx dy dz aw ea ag b ah ai eb ak ec ed j dl ee az "
browser.find_element_by_xpath(".//button[@class='"+new+"']).click()
```

result:It should navigate to web and and click the button

```
error:
    browser.find_element_by_xpath(".//button[@class='"+new+"']").click()
  File "/home/venky/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 394, in find_element_by_xpath
    return self.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value=xpath)
  File "/home/venky/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 978, in find_element
    'value': value})['value']
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":".//button[@class='dt du dv bs dw dx dy dz aw ea ag b ah ai eb ak ec ed j dl ee az ']"}
  (Session info: chrome=73.0.3683.103)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=73.0.3683.68 (47787ec04b6e38e22703e856e101e840b65afe72),platform=Linux 4.10.0-28-generic x86_64)
```

Comment: Is there a button with this class(dt du dv...) on the page? The selenium tells you it cant find it on the page...

Comment: yes ,it is a button

Comment: And its class name is "dt du dv bs.... "?

Comment: yes its dynamically changing per each user

Comment: So you need to put in the specific value the selenium agent gets when it loads the page or think of another way identifying this button...

Comment: You could also 'just' try every option using a loop and try except mechanism until you find the correct one

Comment: it will work when i use xpath using text()..